# Python pandas dataframe to better display sublist

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following data:

```
data = {'class': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
'score': [ 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
'fruit': [['apple1', 'pear1', 'guava1'], ['apple2', 'pear2'], ['guava3']]}
```

Does anyone know how pandas dataframe display the data as below:

```
  class     fruit   score
     a1    apple1      b1
            pear1
           guava1
     a2    apple2      b2
            pear2
     a3    guava3      b3
```

Actually, the data above I am trying to simplify the situation. The real situation is there may be several columns like 'fruit', such as the following:

```
data2 = {'class': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
'score': [ 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
'fruit': [['apple1', 'pear1', 'guava1'], ['apple2', 'pear2'], ['guava3']],
'motor': [['car1', 'truck1'], ['car2', 'truck2', 'van2'], ['car3', 'van3']]}
```

I hope to display like this using pandas dataframe:

```
class     fruit   motor   score
   a1    apple1    car1      b1
          pear1  truck1   
         guava1
   a2    apple2    car2      b2
          pear2  truck2
                   van2
   a3    guava3    car3      b3
                   van3
```

I have tried DaFanta's solution, but I don't know how to apply to the second or third column like this. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

`a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) 
open_df = a[['score', 'class']].join(a['fruit'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))) 
open_df.set_index(['score', 'class']).stack()`

Comment: Thanks. It works if I have one column like 'fruit'. However, I have more than one column like 'fruit', how can I apply your suggested answer to this?